# SQL Server create report of emails

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `SpeakerSessions` that contains these columns:

```
Created - datetime
Processed - float (boolean)
Dateprocessed - datetime
Conference - varchar
Session - varchar
FDBue - datetime
Speaker - varchar
Email - varchar
Type - varchar
ID - int
```

What I want is a query, report, or view that will show me what sessions a speaker is presenting at, and the due date of their presentation content, something similar to:

```
speaker  conference     session     fbdue
-----------------------------------------------------
Joe         Conf1       SessionA    1/1/2010
            Conf1       SessionB    1/1/2010
            Conf2       SessionE    1/10/2010
Amy         Conf1       SessionA    1/3/2010
            Conf2       SessionB    1/3/2010
```

How can I achieve this in SQL Server? The `ID` column is an identity column. The same speaker can speak at multiple sessions at the conference.

Comment: Are you looking for the speaker row to only appear once and not have multiple Joe's and Amy's?

Comment: @Zi0n1 Yes! Exactly. Speaker to appear once and then have their conferences and sessions to appear on the same row and how ever many rows after that are needed.

Comment: This is a straightforward `select`. Have you even attempted to do this for yourself?

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, however in a "straightforward select" the speaker name will be displayed on each row, which I do not want.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't really highlight that as the biggest hurdle you were having. `case when row_number() over (partition by speaker order by conference, session) = 1 then speaker end`

Comment: This requirement would usually be handled on the front end with a reporting tool.

Comment: @shawnt00 can you explain your case statement?

Comment: You mentioned "email" in the question title but I'm not sure if that fits into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    case
        when row_number() over (
                 partition by coalesce(speaker, email)
                 order by conference, session
             ) = 1
        then coalesce(speaker, email)
    end as speaker,
    conference, session, fbdue
from SpeakerSessions
order by coalesce(speaker, email), conference, session;
```

This problem amounts to knowing which row is the first in a series of rows. That kind of information can't be determined by looking within the row itself.

Looking around at other rows is basically what analytic/window functions are all about. `row_number()` is one that applies a numbering to a set of rows in the designated order. The `partition by` limits the numbering to each speaker and allows it to reset on the next one. The `order by` is also important and much match the `order by` of the query results (after `speaker`).

Ultimately the expression says this: if we're at the first row then return the name of the speaker otherwise return a null (blank). Depending on how you plan to use this you may prefer to return an empty string with `else ''` instead of the default null.

Many reporting tools have a "suppress repeated values" option to handle this logic for you. It would also be easy to do this in Excel with a formula that looks at the previous cell if you were pulling data into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Wow that's almost exactly what I'm looking for! I had to order by email instead of speaker name because the Nulls were showing up first. When I run this however, there are duplicates when there shouldn't be. Each speaker appears once but there are duplicate conference-session-fbdue

Comment: @z0nia There's no way for this query to introduce duplicates that weren't already in the data. I suppose some rows could *appear* to be dups but they would have to be shuffled from the expected ordering. It's hard to make guesses without seeing the data. Perhaps the `row_number()` doesn't match the final `order by`.

Comment: In the SpeakerSessions table there is one speakerA who is presenting at one conference and only doing one session. The query results show speakerA - confA - sessionA - fbdue. The row directly under that shows the same exact thing except the speaker is null: null -confA - sessionA - fbdue

Comment: @z0nia Well based on your previous comment you're apparently doing something with null speakers/email addresses. It probably means that the `partition by` is wrong.

Comment: If I didn't make the change then the multiple sessions a speaker is presenting at wouldn't show up in order by speaker. It would show up as null speaker

Comment: @z0nia I hope this doesn't come off as too gruff: you haven't specified exactly what that change was. You didn't mention null speakers in the question either. I just need specific information before I can offer much more help

Comment: I apologize, the change I made was after FROM I ordered by email instead of speaker

Comment: @z0nia I've edited my answer with a guess. I would be best if you edited the question to show the results you desire. It should include an example of a row with this null speaker/email.